# Destroying a function in javascript before calling it again

Tags: javascript, html

I have created a website. While the user opens it for the first time, javascript calls( `showDetails()` ) a function (Which does a few tasks in the backend), I also have updated the button in my website, when the user presses it the same function will be called again ( `showDetails()` ) and does the same task.

But the problem here is that when the user presses the update button another instance of showDetails will be created and two instances will be executing in the background. (If user presses update 5 times 5 instances of the `showDetails()` function will be created).

I have tried to resolve this by assigning a function to an variable and destroying it like this:

```
//creating variable
var variShow = null;

//calling showdetails() when user opens the site and assigning it to variable variShow
variShow = showdetails();

//when user presses update button checking whther variShow is null or not. if not null assign it to null and call showdetails() again.
if (variShow !== null) {
    variShow = null;
}
variShow = showdetails();
```

But it still does not work, how can I resolve this?

Comment: is there any async call inside the other function?

Comment: could you show the full code?

Comment: @brk It has some web server calls(which happens repeatedly) ,

Comment: @Boney I think i have simplified  my problem , If i put my actual code here it will be bit complicated. If you need more information you can ask me.

Comment: When you call `variShow=showdetails();`, the `variShow` is null until `showdetails()` is finish, that means while `showdetails()` is running in the background, user can still trigger `showdetails()`.

Comment: @Solomon Tam okay ,Then how can i check whther any instance of `showdetails()` are executing in background, if so destroy them?

Comment: You can't destroy an `execution context`. If you really need to interrupt the execution of a function, you will need add check point in the middle of the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is solution : 
  You can do it with flag but this is better just use override on the end !

```js
var showDetails = function() {

   console.log("Active method!")
  // function 
  // your code here 

  // Override self
  showDetails = function(){console.log("not active any more")}  
}


// Just for test 
showDetails();

// Just for test again
showDetails();
```

We override function to make nothing on call (empty):

```
   showDetails = function(){}
```

Then you will avoid error on other call showDetails();

If you put :

```
   showDetails = null;
```

then this will produce 'showDetails()' error. You can make it null or

```
   showDetails = undefined;
```

but then you must check before any call :

```
 // This is strong check work on all old and new browsers
  if (typeof showDetails !== 'undefined' && typeof showDetails === "function") {
    showDetails()
  }
```

```js
var showDetails = function() {

   console.log("Active method!")
  // function 
  // your code here 
  showDetails = undefined;
  
  // modern js
  // delete showDetails
  
}

// First time call
showDetails();


// This is strong check work on all old and new browsers
if (typeof showDetails !== 'undefined' &&
    typeof showDetails === "function") {
    // Second call must be protected/checked
    showDetails()
    
} else {
   console.log("Not active method!");
}
```

Comment: In above code function will destroy itself at the end of it's execution right?

Comment: @PavanShetty You cannot explicitly destroy a function in js. In fact I don't think you can in any language. What you're trying to do is to *debounce* a function. That means you can prevent the same function call from being repeatly executed in a short period of time.

Comment: After the first call to a debounced function, subsequent call is nullified (call is made, but has no effect) for a period of time. This answer is saying basically same idea. It's not strictly a debounced function implementation, but it does prevent subsequent call to take effect.

Comment: Setting variable to an function helped to resolve this. Actually i didnt even have to override it on the end!

Answer (score 0):

```
var interrupted = false;

function showDetails(){

    interrupted = false;

    //Some task
    //...

    //Check if someone interrupt the function at some point of the function
    if(interrupted){
        //Some code to handle interruption here
        //...
        interrupted = false;
        return;
    }

    //Some task
    //...

    interrupted = false

}
```

When user enter the page

```
showDetails();
```

When user press button

```
interrupted = true;
var waitInterval = setInterval(function(){
    //Wait until the running function to be terminated.
    if(!interrupted){
        clearInterval(waitInterval);
        showDetails();
    }
}, 100)
```